# Bulk export and import Azure B2C users and custom attributes

Tags: azure

Is there an Azure feature to bulk export users with passwords from the current organization Azure B2C AD and import another organization Azure B2C AD?

Comment: this link will help you--https://blog.kloud.com.au/2018/10/30/bulk-import-users-into-azure-ad-b2c-tenant-with-custom-attributes/